# Modifying Directory using Devise Ldap Authenticator gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

Is it possible to manage ACL and modify the directory (create entries / modify entries ) using devise ldap gem. I can successfully authenticate users but have not found any way of performing the above mentioned processes.